# Connecting signals coming from widgets in a QVector

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm working on the following Window with QT:

[image]

For my rows i have the following structure:

```
typedef struct
{
    struct{
        int x;
        int y;
        int width;
        int height;
        int layer;
        int idx;
    }outputSettings;

    QDoubleSpinBox *xSpinBox;
    QDoubleSpinBox *ySpinBox;
    QDoubleSpinBox *heightSpinBox;
    QDoubleSpinBox *widthSpinBox;
    QDoubleSpinBox *layerSpinBox;

    // Checkboxes
    QCheckBox *channelCheckBox;
}myUI;

QVector<myUI> inputBoxes;   // Create a row of input boxes per channel
```

I then create them in a for loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < inputChannels; ++i)
{
    inputBoxes[i].channelCheckBox = new QCheckBox;
    inputBoxes[i].channelCheckBox->setChecked(true);

    inputBoxes[i].xSpinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox;
    inputBoxes[i].xSpinBox->setRange(minXPos, maxXPos);
    inputBoxes[i].xSpinBox->setSingleStep(1);
    inputBoxes[i].xSpinBox->setValue(0);
    inputBoxes[i].xSpinBox->setDecimals(0);
    connect(inputBoxes[i].xSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this, SLOT(setXValue(double)));

    inputBoxes[i].ySpinBox = new QDoubleSpinBox;
    inputBoxes[i].ySpinBox->setRange(minYPos, maxYPos);
    inputBoxes[i].ySpinBox->setSingleStep(1);
    inputBoxes[i].ySpinBox->setValue(0);
    inputBoxes[i].ySpinBox->setDecimals(0);
    connect(inputBoxes[i].ySpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), this, SLOT(setYValue(double)));
```

...

Now i get stuck on the connect. I want to connect the valueChanged property of my spinboxes to my outputSettings struct. This struct will be my return type at the end.
I implemented the following slots:

```
public slots:
void setXValue(double x){inputBoxes[0].outputSettings.x = int(x);}
void setYValue(double y){inputBoxes[0].outputSettings.y = int(y);}
```

...

But here i don't know what vector item called the function. (currently i just entered inputBoxes[0] as a dummy)
My first idea was to add an extra parameter int channel. But then the connect doesn't work. So i tried to work around that with QMapper. But that doesn't seem to be a good option to me and i didn't really get it running.

I would largely appreciate if someone could help me out here or at least point me in the right direction.

Cheers.

Comment: One option is to use the `setProperty` of spin box widget to store the index, and then to get it by `QObject::sender()` , second is to use a lambda function in your connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement it by using a lambda function in your connect

```
  connect(inputBoxes[i], static_cast<void (QDoubleSpinBox::*)(double)>(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
            [i](double value)
    {
        // use i as your vector index here 
        handleDoubleSpinBoxChanged(i, value);
    });
```

Then you can change your slot function to

```
void handleDoubleSpinBoxChanged(int i, double value)
{
   inputBoxes[i].outputSettings.x = int(x);
}
```

Second option is to get the spin box index from the sender object
you will have to store it first inside your loop

```
inputBoxes[i].xSpinBox->setProperty("index",i);
```

Then you can get it

```
void MainWindow::setXValue(double d)
{
    QDoubleSpinBox * sb = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox *>(QObject::sender());
    int iCallerVectorIndex = -1;

    if (sb != Q_NULLPTR)
    {
        iCallerVectorIndex = sb->property("index").toInt(); // to get the caller index.
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely better than my answer below, I leave mine just for reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! With option one I'm not quite sure how to differentiate which spinBox (x or y or height...) was changed within "handleDoubleSpinBoxChanged" 
For now i'll just go with your second option :)

Comment: @LisaAusten, for the first option just add two connections, one for each slot. for example, the first spin box `X` can connect to `HandleX` and for the second spin box `Y` connect to  `HandleY`

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, in your SLOT method you can call sender() to retrieve the object who emitted the signal. You can compare in a loop the spinBoxes of each of your inputBoxes to find out what caused the SLOT to execute, something like:

```
// in your SLOT method:
for (int i = 0; i < inputChannels; i++){
  if (inputBoxes[i].xSpinBox == (QDoubleSpinBox *)sender()){
    // the xSpinBox of the i-th inputBox emitted the signal
    break();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just make myUI a QObject and add slot function there.
You wouldnt need any indexes then.

```
typedef struct
{
    Q_OBJECT
    struct{
        int x;
        int y;
        int width;
        int height;
        int layer;
        int idx;
    }outputSettings;

    QDoubleSpinBox *xSpinBox;
    QDoubleSpinBox *ySpinBox;
    QDoubleSpinBox *heightSpinBox;
    QDoubleSpinBox *widthSpinBox;
    QDoubleSpinBox *layerSpinBox;

    // Checkboxes
    QCheckBox *channelCheckBox;
public slots:
setXValue(double);
setYValue(double);
}myUI;
```

Example of connect call:

```
 connect(inputBoxes[i].ySpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), inputBoxes[i], SLOT(setYValue(double))
```

or you can call connect in constructor of myUI:

```
myUI() {
    connect(xSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), 
        this, SLOT(setXValue(double))
    connect(ySpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), 
        this, SLOT(setYValue(double))
}
```

I think that would be much simpler and intuitive because your object is responsible to setting his own members and you dont need to remember any indexes.